# How to grab data using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following pattern:

```
    private const string _usernamePattern = "Username: <strong>.*</strong>";
```

and code:

```
    private string Grab(string text, string pattern)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
        if (!regex.IsMatch(text))
            throw new Exception();
        else
            return regex.Match(text).Value;

    }
```

so, it works fine for string like:

```
Username: <strong>MyUsername</strong>
```

But I need grab only `MyUsername`, without `<strong>` tags. 
How to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't really be doing this with regex and you should use a dedicated html parser..

See this question as to why

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

However, if this is an extremely limited case and not lumps of html, and all you want is the text between two tags, you could just use the following pattern...

- Zero-width positive lookbehind assertion
- Zero-width positive lookahead assertion

```
(?<=<strong>).*?(?=</strong>)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
private const string _usernamePattern = "Username: <strong>(?<Email>.*)</strong>";
...
private string Grab(string text, string pattern)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);

    if (!match.Success)
        throw new Exception();
    else
        return match.Groups["Email"].Value;
}
```